# Javascript AJAX call shows empty $_SESSION in PHP program

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I am using AJAX to store the first 4 digits of a credit card in $_SESSION["first4"] number during the onBlur event. I have a sample which works flawlessly. Then I take that good code and stick it a shopping cart we purchased from Clearcart (we now own the code). The issue is that the $_SESSION variable is always empty in the AJAX php receiver program. Here is the entirety of the program:

```
$sessionName = "ClearCart20UserSession";
if (isset($_REQUEST[$sessionName])) session_id($_REQUEST[$sessionName]);
$started = session_start();
$_SESSION["first4"] = isset($_GET["first4"])?$_GET["first4"]:"";
```

After that fourth line of code the following variables are **dumped**: (i.e. these are output values not assignment statements)

```
$started = 1
session_id=4f920c1fe5e2078d95f7700ece674659
$_REQUEST=Array
(
    [first4] => 5554
    [PHPSESSID] => 4f920c1fe5e2078d95f7700ece674659
    [ClearCart20UserSession] => 4f920c1fe5e2078d95f7700ece674659
)
$_SESSION=Array  
(
    [first4] => 5554
)
```

$_SESSION in the calling program literally contains thousand of variables. Yet, here in the receiver it is empty except for the variable I set.

Notes:

1) That is the same session_id/PHPSESSID as in the calling program - I have dumped it. (When I say calling program I mean the php program which generated the html form; obviously the actual 'calling' program is the javascript in the browser)

2) The http type and domain are identical (both are https:). I have put the receiver ajax program in the same directory as the caller just to eliminate any cross-domain issues.

3) The session save path is /tmp and when I look in that folder the sess_4f920c1fe5e2078d95f7700ece674659 file exists. (Although it seems smaller than I would expect with thousands of variables).

4) When I go back a page in my browser and then forward to re-show formerly saved session variables (i.e. things like form input values) they still exist so the AJAX recipient is not clearing $_SESSION as the empty array might imply.

5) The shopping cart uses cookies and the cookie values are correctly reflected in $_REQUEST as expected.

6) I added session_write_close() to the end of the main/caller program to ensure the session file is not open. Should not matter as the caller php terminates and nothing happens till the javascript event fires AJAX.

7) FWIW session.upload_progress.enabled is on.

8) Curiously the shopping cart uses AJAX for its own purposes which I believe is working fine. Regardless, I don't see how that could impact me - its completely different AJAX called and received by different javascript and php respectively.

9) As mentioned above, this virtually identical code works in a test sample I developed where I even mimic using cookies.

10) I have read several dozen postings on this issue but none have fixed my problem. Most seem to be related to not using session_start or having the right session_id.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the shopping cart software changed the session folder with this line of code:

session_save_path("tmpsession");

Hence, even though the session_id's were identical the session files were stored in two different folder locations (the AJAX file was in /tmp and the main calling program was using www/tmpsession).